# Compare date from string with current date

Tags: powershell

I am have string which contain date and I want to compare that all last 15 days date with the date in string.

I have stored all 15 days date in array and comparing with the date in string.

```
#last 15 days date.
$Q = @()
$Q = for ($i=15; $i -gt 1; $i--) {
    $date=Get-Date -DisplayHint Date #-Format "dd MMM yyyy"
    $final=$date.AddDays(-$i)
    $final.tostring("dd MMM yyyy")
}

# $array.'Description' have string like this "Enabled AD ID as per Call id: 509112 29 Oct 2019"

#comparing
if($array.'Description' -notcontains $Q){
Write-host ("true")
}else
{
write-host ("false")
}
```

I want comparing result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should always compare dates to dates, not their string representation unless it is in [Sortable format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier).

Below code takes the date string from the Description attribute and converts it to a local DateTime object to compare against:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15).Date  # midnight 15 days ago

$array | ForEach-Object {
    # parse a date object from the Description string
    $dateString = ([regex]'(\d{1,2} \w{3} \d{4})$').Match($_.Description).Groups[1].Value
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'd MMM yyyy', [cultureinfo]"en-US")
    # make it a Local date
    $date = [datetime]::SpecifyKind($date, 'Local')

    if ($date -gt $refDate) {
        # the description date is inside the last 15 days
        Write-Host "True"
    }
    else { Write-Host "False" }
}
```

---

**Edit**

As per [Esperanto57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735690/esperento57)'s comment, in case the Description string does not contain a date to parse, below uses a `try{..} catch{..}` block to tackle that:

```
$array | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        # parse a date object from the Description string
        $dateString = ([regex]'(\d{1,2} \w{3} \d{4})$').Match($_.Description).Groups[1].Value
        $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'd MMM yyyy', [cultureinfo]"en-US")
        # make it a Local date
        $date = [datetime]::SpecifyKind($date, 'Local')
        if ($date -gt $refDate) {
            # the description date is inside the last 15 days
            Write-Host "True"
        }
        else { Write-Host "False" }
    }
    catch {
         Write-Host "False. (The Description attribute does not contain a date.)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forget the case of 'Description' column dont have date and you should be test future date too, but i vote for your solution ;)

Comment: @Esperento57 The OP says the Description string **contains the date**. If this is not the case, the code simply exits with errors. If need be, it is very simple to add a check for that of course or wrap it inside a `try{..}catch{..}` block

Comment: all last 15 days : for me stop of today (not futur date). I use try catch for intercept exception not when a cant test my-self not you? For me, if date dont exist you should retur false, but its just my opinion. Have a good day

Answer (score 2):

You can split `$array.'Description'`, then join the last three elements and then compare it with $Q.
`($($array.'Description').Split(" ") | Select-Object -Last 3) -join " "`
The comparison would look something like:

```
if ((($($array.'Description').Split(" ") | Select-Object -Last 3) -join " ") -notcontains $Q){
    Write-host ("true")
}else
{
    write-host ("false")
}
```